# What Flash button generators are there?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, flash, multimedia

I have a client that wants to have Flash buttons on their website. As much as I hate Flash, I am trying to comply with their request.

I have not been able to find a single Flash button generator for Ubuntu at all. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

I'd personally stick with your gut feeling and reject their request for Flash buttons for a few reasons:

1. Search engines won't spider through them (essentially hurting the site's ranking).
2. Pages take longer to load because Flash adds a lot of overhead on low-powered systems. They won't work at all on things that don't support Flash (read: millions of smart phones).
3. Buttons are harder to edit and maintain.

The first two should be justification enough for the client.

If you ***need*** a button to do something fancy, I'd look to Javascript. Unless you're getting really whacky, you can do simple animations, even play sound (but a plea from the internet: please don't) in a nice, accessible way.

StackOverflow is probably a more helpful place for specific help on doing something like that though.

Comment: Sadly, you and I know that but the people who are going to write my paycheck don't. They refuse to listen and I need the income so I am not going to refuse to do the site because they are insisting on it.  Guess I will have to get a windows machine to get the button done, but thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've worked with clients who want splash screens and Flash navigation but I've actually been fairly successful explaining the downsides of Flash because there are such strong **business** reasons for not using it. Reasons based on the result of diminished sales through poorer traffic. It's in *their* interest to not want it, you just have to educate. And as I've said, there are accessible alternatives that can deliver similar effects.

Answer (score 2):

You could use online button(and other effects) generators like [this](http://www.effectgenerator.com/) or [this](http://www.webestools.com/flash-button-maker-animation-swf-free-flash-button-generator-online-web20.html).

You could also use [css3 gradient buttons](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons/) instead of flash.